# Maven Project : How to specify a relative path in a *.ini file?

Tags: java, maven, relative-path, ini

In a Maven project, I have a settings.ini file in this directory :

```
|-src/main/resources/configurations
```

The `settings.ini` file, needs to refer to another file, `tempDB.sql` under this directory :

```
|-src/main/resources/databases
```

So, I tried this relative path in my `settings.ini` file, but it didn't work:

```
temp_database = ../databases/tempDB.sql
```

How do I specify a relative path in my `.ini` file?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As the path will not be read by the .ini file itself, your code will use the project root directory as the start. In this case, you should use:

```
|-src/main/resources/databases/tempDB.sql
```

Comment: Perfect! +1. waiting for some seconds to accept ur answer :)

Answer (score 3):

Be careful with @renke's answer. This won't work in any environment other than your development environment, because the project's source will not be available in other environments. A better solution is to have the resource file reference the filename `temp_database=resource/tempDB.sql`, and then load the file as a classpath resource in java `"classpath:" + tempDatabase` (assuming tempDatabase holds the property value read from your ini file). If this file isn't supposed to be available to your java code then it shouldn't be in src/main/resource in the first place.

Comment: I so want to edit your typo from "Joas" to "Joao," but it's too small of a change, and your grammar is too darn good for me to find anything else to change.  Curses.

Comment: Actually, I'm not happy with the second sentence, although technically it's well formed, conversationally it would be more correct to lead with the second clause, i.e.: Because..., this won't work. I've fixed the typo myself, you lazy bugger (thanks) :)

Comment: Ha!  Hey, it's not my fault!  I was literally disallowed! =P